# CSF on CentOS not removing tempban/tempdeny

Tags: centos, csf

I have CSF v5.12 (generic) installed on my CentOS 4.4 server, and am trying to use the tempban/tempdeny feature to temporary add a firewall block to a specific IP. 
(I am building a PHP script which needs to block abusive users for an hour)

The command I am running is:

```
[root@domfe01 csf]# /usr/sbin/csf --tempdeny 175.107.146.57 10
DROP  all opt -- in !lo out *  175.107.146.57  -> 0.0.0.0/0  
csf: 175.107.146.57 blocked on port * for 10 seconds inbound
```

However, more than 10 seconds later and the IP is still blocked.

I don't really know what to do next, as CSF appears to function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be best to ask Chirpy (the author) himself. 
I ran into some quirkeness some time ago and he was an excellent help. 
visit [ConfigServer](http://configserver.com/contact.html) and write a comment there for a quick response.

your command does appear correctly -

you could however always write a script to remove from the csf.deny any item that is over 1 hour old instead

Comment: Thanks, I've posted on their forums. Hopefully I'll get a solution either here or there soon.

Comment: One of our admin's fixed it for me. LFP(?) wasn't running as a service, as a perl module was missing. The temp ban stuff works fine now.

Comment: It was probably LFD, not LFP.  It stands for Login Failure Daemon, and is the daemon that runs a bunch of CSF's features.